# w2ui - how show text from cell in an overlay?

Tags: overlay, w2ui

there is some way to show all the contents of a cell in an overlay

My problem is show log text

version 1.4
[image]

Comment: A poorly described question. Add more details, your code trials, etc. Read how to ask good question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that had been mentioned

https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/issues/350